# SQL condition statement for strings

Tags: mysql

I am trying to Write a query that produces the title of every action film with a rating of PG-13, R, or NC-17.

Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT title 
FROM film
INNER JOIN film_category ON film.film_id = film_category.film_id
INNER JOIN category ON film_category.category_id = category.category_id
WHERE category.name = "Action"
WHERE film.rating = "PG-13" OR "R" OR "NC-17";
```

I believe the problem is in my syntax in my film.rating conditioning. I am new to SQL. I would appreciate if someone could show me in the right direction!

Comment: use `'` instead of `"`

Comment: you can have only ONE `where` clause. if you need multiple conditions, it has to be a proper boolean logic statement. `where foo OR bar`

Comment: You *can not* chain the OR like that. You need to prefix each field separate, like so: film.rating = "PG-13" OR film.rating = "R" OR film.rating ="NC-17". better use IN ('PG-13', 'R') like @SebastianBrosch shows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT title 
FROM film f INNER JOIN film_category fc ON f.film_id = fc.film_id
    INNER JOIN category c ON fc.category_id = c.category_id
WHERE c.name = 'Action'
AND f.rating IN ('PG-13', 'R', 'NC-17');
```

Comment: Syntax is wrong, but `IN` clause is what he should be using. Check you from statement

Answer (score 2):

You have several errors in your SQL.  I would write this as:

```
SELECT f.title 
FROM film f INNER JOIN
     film_category fc
     ON f.film_id = fc.film_id INNER JOIN
     category c
     ON fc.category_id = c.category_id
WHERE c.name = 'Action' AND f.rating IN ('PG-13', 'R', 'NC-17');
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Qualify all column names when you have more than one table in the query.
- `WHERE` is used at most one time per `SELECT`.
- `OR` is for boolean expressions, not constants.  You want `IN`.
- Single quotes are the SQL standard for string delimiters.